# RestTemplate.exchange method error: not applicable arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm seeing an error message when trying to run a sample program on Sprint boot, while using Eclipse based Spring Suite. I have JDK11 installed in the mac that I'm currently using

**Error Message:**
The method exchange(URI, HttpMethod, HttpEntity, Class) in the type RestTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (URI, Http.HttpMethod, HttpEntity, Class)

Initially the exchange method was in this form: `exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);`

When url was a String. Since the method required URI object, I changed the code.
Also in my hunt for a solution, I also converted the null parameter to an object.

```
public String secondWayOfCalling() {
    RestTemplate template = builder.build();
    List<ServiceInstance> instances= clientOnly.getInstances("client-service-name");

    URI uri = instances.get(0).getUri();
    ResponseEntity<String> entity = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, 
            new HttpEntity<String>("parameters"), String.class);

    return entity.getBody();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks correct, if you get such an error I am pretty sure you messed up with your imports, check that your used classes come from following packages:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import java.net.URI;
```

I bet your URI class comes from a wrong one.